# Density function of the mixture of two non-homogeneous Poisson processes

Tags: poisson-distribution, kernel-smoothing, mixture-distribution

I'd like to know how can I calculate the density function of the mixture of two non-homogeneous Poisson process. I should mention that I have the kernel densities of those NHPP s.

I can also describe my question as follows: I have two layers that are connected to each other. the number of defects in each of them has NHPP and I'd like to calculate the overall failure intensity of the system (The system will fail when the density of defects in both layers reach a certain limit).

Answer (score 1):

If Poisson Process A, having intensity function lambda_A(t), is independent of Poisson Process B, having intensity function lambda_B(t), then A + B (which is not a mixture, but is what you intend from your stated failure rate context) is a Poisson Process having intensity function lambda_A+B(t) = lambda_A(t) + lambda_B(t).

See Fact 1.15 of http://www.actuarialseminars.com/Misc/PPjwd.pdf , and see derivation in homogeneous case at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Independent_Poisson_Random_Variables_is_Poisson .  I leave it as an easy exercise for you to show the result is true in the non-homogeneous case.

If the two Poisson Processes are not independent, there are many possibilities as to the distribution of their sum, and the calculations get more complicated. Independence is a critical assumption in failure analysis which can dramatically impact the result. Many people assume independence even when not justified, and as a consequence, their estimate of system failure rate (or probability) can be off by orders of magnitude. Maybe in your case independence actually holds, but you should carefully check (unless this is just a homework problem for which no real thinking should be applied).